# Setting a column on TZQuery.ParamByName

Tags: delphi, zeos

I need to run a `SELECT` statement where the column names are variable, as follows:

```
query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT A.:COLUMN '+
                  '  FROM A         ';

query.ParamByName('COLUMN').AsString := 'column_name';
query.Open();
```

But when I do this, there's an error in the SQL syntax because the component runs as:

```
SELECT A.'column_name'
  FROM A
```

Is there a way to set these parameters without the quotes so I can dynamically choose columns?

Comment: In Firedac i use "Macros". For Zeos see http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/search.php?keywords=macros

Comment: @AnselmoMS it seems like macros was used in a very old version, as I'm using one of the last versions, macros are not available in my component, which is a bummer, seemed like a good solution

Answer (score 1):

You can change your query as follow (create subqueries with all columns). All columns that you select have to be the same type:

```
select myData
from (
  select col1 as myData, 'col1' as colName from A
  union all
  select col2, 'col2' from A
  union all
  select colLast, 'colLast' from A
  ) as mTbl
where colName=:COLUMN
```